# Better approach for stream filter in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

Is there a way to simplify filter using stream?
Or for it to be shorter or optimized? I'm not quite sure if using a for loop would be better to use in this scenario.

I'm just trying to separate the failed and the success messages using the failedIds.

Here is my code

```
List<Message> successMessages = messageList.stream()
        .filter(message -> !failedMessageIds.contains(message.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Message> failedMessages = messageList.stream()
        .filter(message -> failedMessageIds.contains(message.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you!

Comment: To *optimize*: don't use streams at all.

Comment: @Olivier - What does that mean and why did you mention it?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 It means that all those stream constructs are fancy but a good old for() loop over the message list is much faster.

Comment: @Olivier - Do you know any article or tutorial which shows when to use for loop vs stream and what are the differences in performance?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 There is an article [here](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html). Basically sequential streams are slower than for loops and parallel streams can be faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `groupingBy` collector here. This solution passes over the collection only once. Also make sure to use a `Set` for `failedMessageIds`.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Message>> messagesByStateMap = messageList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> !failedMessageIds.contains(m.getId())));
List<Message> successMessages = messagesByStateMap.get(true);
```

A much better approach would be to use the `partitioningBy` collector as stated in the following comment since your classifier function is a just a `Predicate`.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Message>> messagesByStateMap = messageList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(m -> !failedMessageIds.contains(m.getId())));
```

However, since the use of streams has sparked some controversy, here's the equivalent iterative solution using Java 8.

```
for (Message message : messageList)
    messagesByStateMap.computeIfAbsent(!failedMessageIds.contains(message.getId()), 
        unused -> new ArrayList<>())
    .add(message);
```

Comment: It's probably just a matter of taste, but I use `groupingBy` if I expect more than two groups in the result map. if there are exactly two groups I prefer `partitioningBy` like: `messageList.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(failedMessageIds::contains));`

Comment: `partitioningBy` collector is more appropriate here since the classifier is a `Predicate`. I have made a mistake and updated the answer with your suggestion. Thanks !

Comment: Without braces, the `for` loop code compromises on the readability in my opinion.

Comment: Well, it is subjective. To me for loop with no braces is more concise.